# Handle index.php and non-www in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a nginx config file that currently handles rewriting of requests via index.php for a Zend Framework application. Example code as follows:

```
server { 
    listen 80 default_server
    etc....

    rewrite ^/index\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }  
    etc....
}
```

However, I now need to add a redirect so that any non-www requests for any domain are processed with a 301 to the www equivalent.

I've come across examples such as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?!www\.)(?<domain>.+)$;
    return 301 $scheme://www.$domain$request_uri;
}
```

But how would I combine everything so that any non-www are first redirected with a 301 and then rewritten via index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two separate server blocks (exactly as you have in your question). The first server block is the default, which handles the `www` prefix domains already, and (presumably) handles the `index.php` rewrite correctly.

The second server block only matches domain names without the `www` prefix.

If you wanted to do it the other way around, that is rewrite `index.php` before you redirect, then just add a rewrite line to the new server block.